# What will be the computational complexity of a system with two pipelined algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotics

A system consists of two separate algorithms (operated in pipeline). `Algorithm#1` is iterated `m` times and has a time complexity of `O(m)`. `Algorithm#2` is iterated `N` times with time complexity `O(N)`. The output of `Algorithm#1` is the input of `Algorithm#2`. Hence, when `Algorithm#1` is fully run (`m` times), `Algorithm#2` is started.

```
system = Algorithm#1 + Algorithm#2
```

For example:

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++) //Algorithm#1
{y=y*i;}

x=y*x;
for (j=0;j<N;j++) //Algorithm#2
{x=x*j;}
```

Here, `*` stands for any operation.

Note that `N>>m`. What will be the final time complexity of the system in terms of Big-O notation?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I couldn't figure out the correct answer, that's why I'm seeking help.

Comment: Hint (If I interprate the question correctly): It's the same complexity as two consecutive statements `algorithm1(); algorithm2();` where algorithmA() takes $O(m)$ and algorithmB() takes $O(N)$ (where`N>m`)

Comment: @santobedi It's fine to seek help, and we know that you're here because you couldn't figure out the correct answer. But you need to tell us where you're stuck. What approach(es) did you try? How did you apply the definitions to the problem?

Comment: @AlbertHendriks Can I write the time complexity of the system as: `O(m)+O(N)` ? In my case, m<5 and N>100. Assuming `O(m)+O(N)` as time complexity of the system, how much is it (time complexity of the system) higher (in terms of time complexity) compared to only `O(N)`? I designed a system that has "extra" `O(m)` time complexity than the existing system with `O(N)` complexity. Now I'm supposed to figure out how much time complexity does the new designed system adds compared to the existing one.

Comment: @Gilles I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the answer to my question. The final complexity will be:

```
O(max(m,N))
```

It is because `m` and `N` are independent and the loops are not nested. In my case, since `N>>m`, the final time complexity will be `O(N)`.